# withServicePath method for additional odata services

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Using the sap-cloud-sdk vdm generation we have generated the code for one of our custom developed odata service

I dont see method withServicePath

Is this method available for services other than standard one as mentioned here
https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/s4hana/datamodel/odata/services/BusinessPartnerService.html#withServicePath-java.lang.String-

Comment: Which version of the generator are you using? And also which kind (maven-plugin, CLI, or java interface)?

Comment: Hi Apoorv Bhargava, if this issue is still relevant to you, please provide the information Christoph has asked for. Otherwise, please provide the answer you found. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Florian , Hi Christoph,  sorry for the delayed update I could successfully use the above mentioned method .above mentioned help doc is correct reference thanks

Comment: Hi Apoorv Bhargava, I'm glad to hear that the issue is resolved. May I ask you to kindly add the answer that you found, so that other people who find this question know about that?

Comment: I would like to share some more details about  the scenario , the knowledge gap I had and the the solution which we found                                                                                            Scenario : Need to provide a feature where service names are configured by customer. So we need to code using cloud sdk in such way that this configured service name is considered.

Comment: Initial Knowledge gap  : From the above mentioned help doc, I got the impression that it is only for cloud sdk inbuild services . Our service is not that kind . we used VDM generation to generate the code.                                                                        Final Understanding: After some more investigation and trials , we could see that the same help doc can be used for our case